# Javascript epoch date incorrect

Tags: javascript, date

I am doing some javascript date stuff, and I executed the following:

```
console.log(new Date(0));
```

I expected to see the *nix Epoch, but I was oddly returned:

```
Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

What happened?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the internal time value, which is UTC, but seeing a string that is based on your system settings, which likely have an offset of UTC-05:00.

The ECMAScript specification explains how the Date constructor and instances work. Given:

```
new Date(0)
```

the Date constructor is called with one argument ([*§20.3.2.2 Date(value)*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value)) so it creates a Date instance with it's internal time value set depending on the type of argument. As the value is a number, the time value is set to that number.

The time value is an offset in milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z [*§20.3.1.1 Time Values and Time Range*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range). Note that it's based on UTC.

The behaviour of *console.log* is entirely implementation dependent, so what you get from:

```
console.log(dateInstance);
```

depends on the host. However, most seem to call the object's *toString* method which returns an implementation dependent string based on the timezone setting for the host system ([*§20.3.4.41 Date.prototype.toString()*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring)). That is, a "local" time.

The timezone offset can be determined using [*getTimezoneOffset*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.gettimezoneoffset). It's in minutes and has the opposite sense to an ISO 8601 offset (e.g. UTC-05:00 will be +300). If you want to get a date string that represents the internal time value without an offset, use [*toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring).

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find any resources explaining it, but this 'error' is due to my timezone (as far as I can tell)

My timezone is `GMT-0500`, which is 5 hours behind UTC time. Add 5 hours to `Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00` and you get the Epoch (`Thurs Jan 1 1970 00:00:00`)

Comment: Well, it tells you right in the output that you're looking at a particular time zone.  Take a look at `(new Date(0)).toISOString()`

Comment: There wouldn't be any resources explaining it, because it just plain old timezones :)